# python - divide world into bins

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, bins

I am working on trying to put moving balls into appropriate bins. I like to think I'm on the right track but I've been stuck for awhile now.

I left code out that didn't seem relevant to my question but if those who answer need further details I can provide them. Basically, I have a world of 200 moving balls. They have an X and Y coordinate. I want to divide the world into square bins of width 256 and place the balls in the appropriate bin.

My approach to this was to put them into a dictionary. It looked like this:

```
dict_of_balls = {}
for i in range(len(balls)):
    xb = int(balls[i].x/256)
    yb = int(balls[i].y/256)
```

and I wanted to make the keys a tuple of the `(xb, yb)` pairs and then place the appropriate balls in that bin but I don't think you can use tuples as keys...

The code is below:

```
import math
import random
import time
import sys


ball_min_radius = 16.0 #world coordinates         
ball_max_radius = 128.0  #world coordniates
number_balls = 200

class Ball:
    """ 
    Implements a point/ball
    """

    def __init__(self):
          self.x = random.uniform(world_min_x,world_max_x)
          self.y = random.uniform(world_min_y,world_max_y)
          self.radius = int(random.uniform(ball_min_radius,ball_max_radius))
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.id < other.id

def main():
    world_min_x = -200.0*number_balls**.5  # minimum x in world coordinates
    world_max_x = +200.0*number_balls**.5  # maximum x in world coordinates
    world_min_y = -200.0*number_balls**.5  # minimum y in world coordinates
    world_max_y = +200.0*number_balls**.5  # maximum y in world coordinates

    balls = [Ball() for i in range(number_balls)]
```

so does anyone have any ideas for how to divide the world into bins based on the given world coordinates? I am unsure of which data structure to use since I can't use tuples for keys. Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: Tuples can be used as dictionary keys.

Comment: @JohnGordon could you provide an example? I don't mean something like `tup = (x,y)` and then the dict is `{tup: someStuff}`, I want something like `{(x, y): someStuff}`. Is the latter possible?

Comment: @donutjuice That exact syntax works.  Try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want a dictionary? Here's how you would do this, but keep in mind you will *only* get one ball per bin because you are specifically casting their key to be (int, int) and keys are unique.

If you use a collection, you can also sort (in my example I sort by the region identifiers):

I am not sure what you are doing that for, but you can do it:

```
import math
import random
import time
import sys


ball_min_radius = 16.0 #world coordinates         
ball_max_radius = 128.0  #world coordniates
number_balls = 200

world_min_x = -200.0*number_balls**.5  # minimum x in world coordinates
world_max_x = +200.0*number_balls**.5  # maximum x in world coordinates
world_min_y = -200.0*number_balls**.5  # minimum y in world coordinates
world_max_y = +200.0*number_balls**.5  # maximum y in world coordinates


class Ball:
    """ 
    Implements a point/ball
    """

    def __init__(self):
          self.x = random.uniform(world_min_x,world_max_x)
          self.y = random.uniform(world_min_y,world_max_y)
          self.radius = int(random.uniform(ball_min_radius,ball_max_radius))
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.id < other.id

    def __str__(self):
        return 'x={x} y={y} r={r}'.format(x=self.x, y=self.y, r=self.radius)

def main():

    balls = [Ball() for i in range(number_balls)]

    dict_of_balls = {}
    ball_collection = []
    for b in balls:
        xb = int(b.x/256)
        yb = int(b.y/256)
        key = (xb, yb)
        dict_of_balls[key] = b

        ball_collection.append((key, b))

    print 'length of dictionary:{}'.format(len(dict_of_balls.keys()))
    print 'length of collection:{}'.format(len(ball_collection))
```

Notice that the dictionary has fewer items than the collection.

You can also print each item this way pretty trivially:

```
    for b in ball_collection:
        print 'ball region: {r}   with coords: {c}'.format(r=b[0], c=b[1])
```

Or, sort them if you want:

```
    print 'Collections also let you sort the collection by region(s)...'
    sorted_list = sorted(ball_collection, key= lambda x: (x[0][0], x[0][1]))


    for b in sorted_list:
        print 'ball region: {r}   with coords: {c}'.format(r=b[0], c=b[1])
```

You can also pretty simply get balls in a specific region too:

```
    print '... or get only ones in a specific region'
    subset =  [b for b in ball_collection if b[0][0] == 1]

    for b in subset:
        print 'ball region: {r}   with coords: {c}'.format(r=b[0], c=b[1])


main()
```

A collection seems to do what you are *actually* wanting.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know if I could make a tuple a key. Is there any way to be able to place more than one ball in a bin? That is what I am going for ideally, but I'm having trouble figuring it out.

Comment: @donutjuice I added a few examples you will probably actually want to use. A dictionary is pretty much by definition not the object you want to use since bins are not unique. Storing them that way is... not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tuple for keys in a dictionary, since tuple is immutable. The only data type you can't use for a dictionary key is a list `[]` or set `{}`

```
**a = {(1,2):'example1', (2,3):'example2'}
>>> a[(1,2)]
'example1'**
```

So I believe this should make it much easier to solve your problem.